# How to delete a directory owned by root but even root without write permission?

Tags: linux, permissions

I created a directory with *root*, and the directory is owned by *root*. But by mistake, I removed write permission for both *root* user and *root* group. So currently *root* has only read and execute permissions for that directory. It looks like:

```shell
# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 12 20:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 12 19:59 ../
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 10 23:28 empty/
```

The *empty* directory is what I want to delete. But of course, it cannot remove or change mode.

```shell
# rm -r empty/
rm: cannot remove 'empty/': Operation not permitted`

# chmod u+w empty/
chmod: changing permissions of 'empty/': Operation not permitted
```

**NB: Don't try it unless you have enough confidence to resolve it.**

Comment: How can I achieve this? Just need one command `chmod -w empty/`

Comment: On what filesystem, what distribution, what security modules (SELinux, etc)? Is there NFS involved, or some other network filesystem?

Comment: This is not a simple permissions problem. `root` would "normally" be able to do this without any issue, see https://pastebin.com/DdHuWdYT It'd probably be good to add the information requested by @user1686, as well as the output of `lsattr`.

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention, it is on my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. I didn't change any default security settings, so the SELinux is disabled. @user1686

Comment: Try `chattr -i -a empty/` followed by `chmod ugo+w empty/`.

Comment: Thanks @mtak. I tried it on my Debian 10, it could be removed by root. It's weird.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, it worked. I think I need to learn more about attributes.

Comment: So, I put the output of `lsattr` here. `----i---------e----- ./empty`

The attribute `i` is the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed with the following commands :

```
chattr -i -a empty/
chmod ugo+w empty/
```

To understand why, please consult the documentation of these commands.
My guess is that you have made this folder to be
immutable by using `chattr +i`.

A file with an immutable attribute cannot be
modified, deleted or renamed.

Only the root (superuser) or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Comment: So he set immutable flag by himself and dont mention this? And complain he cant delete?

Comment: Hi @gapsf , yes I am. I set the flag by myself and complain I can't delete. Actually, the immutable flag was set by a script before, I totally forgot it.
But thanks to those guys' help, I believe I won't forget to check immutable flag next time.